# FastAPI docker-compose File Not Found Error

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, fastapi, cookiecutter

I have to run a project generated by [full-stack-fastapi-postgresql](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql) and I'm stuck at the first step of launching the app: `docker-compose up -d` throws a FileNotFoundError.
I am pretty sure that it's not a hard problem or an issue, just I am missing something but I have no idea why. See the Commands runned version, I'm pretty sure that my error is here.

#### Versions:

`Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46`
`docker-compose version 1.27.4, build unknown`
`Poetry version 1.1.4`

#### Commands runned:

`pip install cookiecutter`

In the section above, I launched downloading and respond all demands like wroted (I just entered "Test" for name, and the result of `openssl rand -hex 32` for each password asked)

```sh
$ cookiecutter https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql
You've downloaded /Users/jojomoon/.cookiecutters/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql before. Is it okay to delete and re-download it? [yes]: yes
project_name [Base Project]: Test
project_slug [test]: 
domain_main [test.com]: 
domain_staging [stag.test.com]: 
docker_swarm_stack_name_main [test-com]: 
docker_swarm_stack_name_staging [stag-test-com]: 
secret_key [changethis]: 1280bf10bc3ebdf435834b2fc98e098144700bd27dfc43f62c2dcdd52741a5ac
first_superuser [admin@test.com]: 
first_superuser_password [changethis]: 81ec188f2f509483aeb7d877376220e81b5e4e1694fc4b1ee11028c923e340e8
backend_cors_origins [["http://localhost", "http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:8080", "https://localhost", "https://localhost:4200", "https://localhost:3000", "https://localhost:8080", "http://dev.test.com", "https://stag.test.com", "https://test.com", "http://local.dockertoolbox.tiangolo.com", "http://localhost.tiangolo.com"]]: 
smtp_port [587]: 
smtp_host []: 
smtp_user []: 
smtp_password []: 
smtp_emails_from_email [info@test.com]: 
postgres_password [changethis]: 39f987c0f2e31a2a594f07eb0e67e2e15766f5a9f93062fc37d0ea66c908279f
pgadmin_default_user [admin@test.com]: 
pgadmin_default_user_password [81ec188f2f509483aeb7d877376220e81b5e4e1694fc4b1ee11028c923e340e8]: 
traefik_constraint_tag [test.com]: 
traefik_constraint_tag_staging [stag.test.com]: 
traefik_public_constraint_tag [traefik-public]: 
flower_auth [admin:81ec188f2f509483aeb7d877376220e81b5e4e1694fc4b1ee11028c923e340e8]: 
sentry_dsn []: 
docker_image_prefix []: 
docker_image_backend [backend]: 
docker_image_celeryworker [celeryworker]: 
docker_image_frontend [frontend]:
```

#### The error

In the README.md generated, they say to install docker, docker-compose and poetry. After this, I launch the `docker-compose up -d` to start the project and then ... (first error and last line shown, more if you want).

```sh
jojomoon at MacBook-Pro-de-Johann in ~/Desktop/entretien/test 
$ docker-compose up -d
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/docker-compose/1.27.4_1/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/docker-compose/1.27.4_1/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1255, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 950, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/docker-compose/1.27.4_1/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  ...
 
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/docker-compose/1.27.4_1/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 212, in _retrieve_server_version
    raise DockerException(
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
```

PLease what did I do wrong?  Have I to fill all the asked values at the beginning? I don't have all of them and I just want to run this boilerplate locally)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you set up docker/virtualbox correctly? E.g for MacOS there's a description [here](https://medium.com/crowdbotics/a-complete-one-by-one-guide-to-install-docker-on-your-mac-os-using-homebrew-e818eb4cfc3). TL;DR copied here:

```
$ brew install docker docker-machine
$ brew cask install virtualbox
-> need password
-> possibly need to address System Preference setting
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
$ docker-machine env default
$ eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
$ docker run hello-world
```

Comment: YES it's working! Thanks! Of course mabe I had some issues with virtualbox (deleting some files when my mac ran out of memory)